# byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData) equvalent in c#

Tags: c#, java, base64, byte, encode

In Java, Apache provides a encoding library namely apache-commons and there is a method that's signiture is

```
byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData)
```

In C#, we try to do the same thing. however, we couldn't find any library or method like this. How we can encode our byte array to Base64 byte array?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) method. This will however *not* return a `byte[]` but a `string` type. To get it in bytes, you will have to perform a text encoding.

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData);
byte[] base64bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64);
```

Comment: I only have byte array and i don't want to use string type in this operation. Additionally, none of encoding types(UTF8, ASCII) work while i trying to encode to base64.

Comment: IIRC, encoding to base 64 is _essentially_ like encoding to an ASCII string anyway. If this isn't working for you, can you post the code that you've tried and how the output isn't what you expect or need?

Comment: var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

This one doesn't work.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Does it throw an error? Does it give you incorrect byte data? (Also, what you posted won't compile; you're redeclaring the `byteArray` while trying to use it in the same line)